# Fill information automatically on .ps1 scripts

Tags: powershell

I want to install an .msi app with a .ps1 script, but I want it to fill some information automatically. For example, see the attached image, what I have to do to instead of `C:\` be `D:\Example\Example`

What should I type on the script?

Thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: Well, what do you have so far? Where are you having trouble in your code? Have you been able to Google this and come up with some code to help you out with?

Comment: The script is done. I just need to know how to do this. I googled it but I don't find something useful.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/.

Answer (score 0):

So for the `.msi` file, in command prompt you can run the following command,

`(filename).msi /?`

A window should appear with the details of command line parameters that you can pass to the `.MSI` file. You should be able to install your application using a command prompt and automate this.